# Book for "linear algebra & multivariable calculus"?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

is there a book that covers linear algebra and multivariable calculus, preferably computationally but with hard (maybe even proof based) exercises. I tried Apostol's Calculus volumes but they seem to adopt a rigorous approach. I am mainly trying to prepare for math 25 which I'm planning to take next year (deferred entry) at harvard.

Comment: I know of no book that does both at the same time.  Is there any reason you would want a book that does so?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Not really but I figured that since textbooks usually have a size limit of around 500 pages, then if I could find a book that did both I would be better off than reading a 500 page treatment of multivariable calculus followed by a 500 page treatment of linear algebra. I am fine with the 500 page treatment of both together (if one exists) being more concise, since I am mathematically mature enough for rigor but at the same time need to learn these topics quickly at a computational level. If you know of any brief treatments of either of these topics I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

In the late 1960s through the mid 1970s there was a slight tendency (in the U.S.) to combine calculus and linear algebra, at least for honors level courses. Two books that I'm fairly familiar with (because I worked through parts of each while in high school) are **[1]** and **[2]** below. While looking up the amazon web pages for these two books I also came across **[3]**, but I don't know anything about this book.

**[1]** [**Calculus of Vector Functions**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013112367X) by Richard E. Williamson and Richard H. Crowell and Hale F. Trotter

**[2]** [**Calculus and Linear Algebra: An Integrated Approach**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0721633706) by Mary R. Embry and Joseph F. Schell and J. Pelham Thomas

**[3]** [**Multivariable Mathematics: Linear Algebra, Multivariable Calculus, and Manifolds**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047152638X) by Theodore Shifrin

Answer (score 2):

The two I know of are [Ted Shifrin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/71348/ted-shifrin)'s [*Multivariable Mathematics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047152638X) and Hubbard and Hubbard's [*Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008VRPQV2).  I've heard good things of both, but I haven't actually read either so I can only recommend them as texts I know others have enjoyed.

Or if you just want short, geometrically motivated treatments of linear algebra and multivariable calculus, try Alan Macdonald's [Linear and Geometric Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1453854932) and [Vector and Geometric Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1480132454).  Each one is only about $200$ pages so reading them back to back is entirely an option.  I have read both of these and they are excellent.  Neither one goes quite as far into the material as I might like, but what they do cover, they do *very* well.  Then again because you're just trying to prepare for future courses, you don't need books that cover everything.

A note though, Macdonald's book do take a little bit different approach than the normal curriculum.  He does everything from a geometric (Clifford) algebra perspective.  I really loved that, and it's certainly not going to hurt to learn some geometric algebra, but it will require a little mental adjustment when you learn it the standard (matrix-based) way at university.

Comment: I can vouch for Shifrin's book, it's quite nice!

Comment: @pjs36 but it's very expensive though

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was [re-asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4485426/a-book-that-brings-together-finite-dimensional-linear-algebra-and-calculus), it'sworth mentioning there are good prospects among the [AMS Open Math Notes](https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes).

- Peter Philip, [Analysis II: Topology and Differential Calculus of Several variables](https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=111307)
- Frank Faris, [Extremely Advanced Calculus: Multivariable Analysis, Vectors, Forms, Metrics](https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=111278)
- Oliver Knill, [Linear Algebra and Vector Calculus](https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110802)